# Everytime I press my button, I want it to create a new div with the new data, but it just changes the one that's already in there, how can I fix this?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I have a fetch api button that gets me a new address every time I press it, and it shows the data in the fields. I want that every time I press the fetch API button, it adds a new div and the new address without deleting the old one:

```
  const fetchapi = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      await axios
        .get("https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/addresses")
        .then((response) => {
          setAllData(response.data);

          console.log(response.data);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <button onClick={fetchapi}>Fetch Location</button>
        {!allData ? null : (
          <div
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#c7c7c7",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              padding: 16,
              margin: 5,
              borderRadius: 20
            }}
          >
            <p>
              <strong>Address: {allData.street_address}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>City: {allData.city}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>Street Name: {allData.street_name}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>Zipcode: {allData.zip_code}</strong>
            </p>
            <button onClick={removeElement}>remove</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

It already fetched the data and remove it if I press the remove button. If someone can help me, would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are maintaining your state as object so whenever new data comes in you're just changing the state with it.

if you want to retain old data also in the page, you have to maintain an array in state.

`setAllData([...allData, response.data]);`

and then render the array with map

```
<Fragment>
  <div>
    <button onClick={fetchapi}>Fetch Location</button>
    {allData.map((data,index)=>(
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#c7c7c7",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          padding: 16,
          margin: 5,
          borderRadius: 20
        }}
      >
        <p>
          <strong>Address: {data.street_address}</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
          <strong>City: {data.city}</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
          <strong>Street Name: {data.street_name}</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
          <strong>Zipcode: {data.zip_code}</strong>
        </p>
        <button onClick={removeElement}>remove</button>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: I placed the [...allData, response.data] inside the fetchapi function.


where do i place the map?

Comment: wrap it around the <div> which displays the fields

Comment: allData is not a function, is a useState..

let [allData, setAllData] = useState({});

Comment: see my edited answer. Also, change the usestate to `let [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);`

Comment: It works!!!!, but now when i press the remove button, it removes all the address. instead of the one i press

Comment: change your remove logic to remove the clicked index data from `allData` array. for ex, if you are removing first index, do removeElement(0)

Comment: this is my removeElement function


 ``` const removeElement = (index) => {
    const newData = [];
    setAllData(newData);
  };```